# Cannot Save Nullable<bool> to Azure Table when its Null

Tags: c#, azure, boolean, nullable, azure-table-storage

For example, I have a `bool? Status` in c#

when the `Status = true/false`, it can save to Azure table, no problem

But when `Stats = null`, it cannot save(**update**) to Azure table, the column still keeps the old value

I guess it might because Azure table does not have a scheme, but whats the solution?

How to save a **null** to **overwrite** the original value?

**EDIT, the code**

data like this:

```
public class someEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

update like this:

```
tableContext.AttachTo("sometable", someEntity);
tableContext.UpdateObject(someEntity);
tableContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch & SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

(I tried `AttachTo` with `"*"` as etag, tried remove `SaveChangesOptions`, neither work)

**SORRY for my stupid, should be this code, then works**

```
tableContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch | SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

Comment: Is the field in the DB allowed to be null?

Comment: I believe yes, if initial value is null, then you can still save. But once you saved as true/false, you can never set back to null again.

Comment: Can you post your code? It's most likely an issue with Nullable<Type> default value being null, and the API disregarding the default value without an explicit update/upsert flag.

Comment: @EricYin Since you've solved this for yourself, I suggest you remove your last update and post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Matthew suggested, I put the answer here

very simple, use:

```
tableContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch | SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

For multiple options, use `| (or)`, not `& (and)`.  [Reason](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-flags)

`SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate = true` means the whole entity will be replaced
`SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate = false`, means merge, the old data will be kept